# Using data from a specific class in python

Tags: python, class

storage = []
...

after running program
storage = [ <**main**.Record instance at 0x032E8530> ]

inside the instance of Record are:

"Model No."
"Standard: Part Number"
"Standard: Issue Date"
 "Date of Declaration"
"Declaration Document Number"

Question: How do I use specific data from within the Record?

Comment: Can you provide the definition of the `Record` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by use?

`storage[0]` will give you a reference to the record.

From there you can just use whatever methods `main.Record` exposes to access its data.